# Highlighting current selected textfield - best approach

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to achieve an effect like this on mobile (ios + android): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcoW8.png

Where the currently selected textfield has a blue tinted icon + underlining

So my framework lacks any support for grey scaling a bitmap image of any sort so  I need to swap between two images to achieve this effect.

My current implementation looks like this:

Please note this for the Titanium Alloy MVC framework but I'm guessing the basic logic should be similar.

I listen for blur/focus events to toggle current image

```
$.firstNameField.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    swapImages($.firstNameField.getParent());
});

$.lastNameField.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
swapImages($.lastNameField.getParent());
});
```

and then I swap images like so:

```
/**
* Swaps between the images (..._0 and ..._1) of an ImageView nested in a
TableRow  
* ..._0 Greyscale image
* ..._0 Colour image
* @param e current TableViewRow
*/
function swapImages(e){
    var imagePathSplit = (e.children[0].image).split('_'); 
    var newImagePath = null;

    if(imagePathSplit[1] == "0.png")
        newImagePath = imagePathSplit[0] + "_1.png";
    else
        newImagePath = imagePathSplit[0] + "_0.png";

    e.children[0].image = newImagePath;
    return;
}
```

This doesn't look that great especially since I need a lot more fields with this functionality, I also want to implement tabbing (using Return key = NEXT) between the fields which will further balloon to increase 1 more event listener per field.

**How would something like this be done ideally?** I can think of one way of just creating the fields in code in array form which should help simplify matters (no more looking too far for Parent/Children, but that would still end up using quite a bit of listeners for switching right?

EDIT: Forgot to add how I have the textFields setup:

```
<TableView id="paypalTable">
<TableViewSection>
    <TableViewRow id="firstNameView" class="tableRow">
        <ImageView id="firstNameIcon" class="textFieldIcon"/>
        <TextField id="firstNameField" class="textField"/>
    </TableViewRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something similar in one of my projects. Although I had an Alloy project I had to use a classic approach to get my desired behaviour.

In my controller:

```
var textFields            = [];
var yourTextFieldsArray   = [];

for (var i = 0; i < yourTextFieldsArray; i++) {
    //Set the selected state to false initially. Maybe you need another command for it.
    textFieldIsSelected[i] = false;
    //create your new view
    textFields[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        top : topValues[i],
        width : Titanium.UI.FILL,
        height : height,
        id : i + 1,
        touchEnabled : true
    });
    textFields[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //Check the source id
        if (e.source.id - 1 > -1) {
            //use your function swapImages(e.source.id). Notice the slightly different parameter since you do not need the complete event.
            swapImages(e.source.id);
        }
}

function swapImages(id){
    //Check the the path variable as you did
    var imagePathSplit = (textFields[i-1].image).split('_'); 
    var newImagePath = null;

    if(imagePathSplit[1] == "0.png")
        newImagePath = imagePathSplit[0] + "_1.png";
    else
        newImagePath = imagePathSplit[0] + "_0.png";

    textFields[i-1].image = newImagePath;
}
```

This approach lets you use the same event listener for every property.

Please notice that my ids start at 1 and **not** at 0. This is because I had to implement such a behaviour for images and ImageViews do not accept `id=0`. My guess is that TextViews don't do it either so you should stick with it. Further notice that you need to decrement the id to get the corresponding object in the `textFields` Array. Otherwise you would get an out of bounds error.

You should create one more event listener for your NEXT event. Implement it in the same way as the first eventListener. Maybe the code is not perfect because I wrote it from my memory. If there are any questions left feel free to ask in the comments.